# regular expression to remove extra spaces from the line in python

Tags: python, regex

```
data =  "        Taylors Lakes, VIC        "
```

I need regular expression to remove extra spaces from this string but not from between the words so that the string looks like this

data =  "Taylors Lakes, VIC"

Comment: This might be helpful later: `s = "   extra      spaces   "; s2 = ' '.join(s.split())` s2 would be "extra spaces". Although, not shown here s has multiple spaces at the ends and middle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. paste your code instead of a screenshot
2. Don't use a regex, but `.strip()` which removes all whitespaces from the beginning and end:

```
data = data.strip()
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need Regex for that. Just use

```
"    abc   ".strip()
```

or

```
data = data.strip()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `strip()` method, it will remove both beginning and ending whitespaces from the string.

```
data = "            Taylors Lakes, VIC            "
print(data.strip())
```

> Output: Taylors Lakes, VIC

However if you still want to use **regex**, below code will do it:

```
import re
data = "            Taylors Lakes, VIC            "

data = re.sub('^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$', '', data)
print(data)
```

> Output: Taylors Lakes, VIC

Answer (score 2):

The solution in **Python 3** is :

```
data = "            Taylors Lakes, VIC       "
print(data.strip())
```

The output is:

```
>>> Taylors Lakes, VIC
```

The solution in **Python 2**:

```
data = "            Taylors Lakes, VIC       "
print data.strip()
```

The output is:

```
>>> Taylors Lakes, VIC
```

Comment: the "python3" solution also works in python2